# Is it possible to get data from the server without passing a tableName parameter? Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Places.php")
Call<List<CountryModel>> getCountries(@Field("tableName") String tableName);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Places.php")
Call<List<CityModel>> getCities(@Field("tableName") String tableName);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Places.php")
Call<List<NeighborhoodModel>> getNeighborhoods(@Field("tableName") String tableName);
```

I have a PHP file named Places.php and this file provides me the data as a JSON array according to the tableName parameter.

Everything is working well but I want to ask is it possible to get the data from the server according to the method name, Not tableName.

For example, If I called the `getCountries` method then that means I want to get countries, Is it possible to do that without inserting the table name parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Create Restful API in PHP and just call the method. [use this exaqmple](https://codeofaninja.com/create-simple-rest-api-in-php/)

Update:

```
 <? PHP 
   require_once ( "SiteRestHandler.php");
   $ view = "";
   if (isset ($ _GET & # 91; "view" & # 93;))
   $ view = $ _GET & # 91 ; "view" & # 93 ;;
   / *
     * RESTful service controller
     * URL mapping
     * /
   switch ($ view) {

   case "all":
   // Handle REST Url / site / list /
   $ siteRestHandler = new SiteRestHandler ();
   $ siteRestHandler -> getAllSites ();
   break;

  case "single":
  // Handle REST Url / site / show / < id> /
  $ siteRestHandler = new SiteRestHandler ();
  $ siteRestHandler -> getSite ($ _GET [ "id"]);
  break;

  case "":
  // 404 - not found;
  break;
  }
?>
```

[learn more](http://www.w3big.com/php/php-restful.html)

Comment: Where is the code part who talking about my request?

Comment: If you want to call Method Name you should create Rest API. see the example In my answer. if you don't know what is REST API see this [link](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-is-a-rest-api)

Comment: In PHP side how can I know which method is called in client side because there 3 methods calls same PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but this part is to be done from PHP code side first then on Android.
The PHP code would look something like this

```
<?php

$api_url = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';

// Read JSON file
$json_data = file_get_contents($api_url);

// Decode JSON data into PHP array
$response_data = json_decode($json_data);

// All user data exists in 'data' object
$user_data = $response_data->data;

// Cut long data into small & select only first 10 records
$user_data = array_slice($user_data, 0, 9);

// Print data if need to debug
//print_r($user_data);

// Traverse array and display user data
foreach ($user_data as $user) {
    echo "name: ".$user->employee_name;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "name: ".$user->employee_age;
    echo "<br /> <br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: In PHP side how can I know which method is called in client side because there 3 methods calls same PHP file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention that all 3 methods are in a single same php file.
So, if you don't wanna send anything to get all neighborhoods, move the neighborhoods method to a separate php file (ex: neighborhoods.php ) and then it'll be a single method call. If you still don't wanna move to a different file then you can't really do anything about it rather than accept it, or maybe change the variable as it don't necessarily has to be the table name but changes will be required from both PHP side and Android.